# ng-repeatで最後のリストにIDを追加する方法

Tags: monaca, angularjs

リストの一番最後に自動スクロールをしたいと考えてます。ng-attr-idと$indexを使えばできそうなのですが、具体的にどんなコードを書けばいいかわかりません。アドバイスお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

最後の要素にだけIDを付けるのであれば`$last`を使用すると簡単だと思います。

```js
app = angular.module('SampleApp', []);
app.controller('SampleCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        return $scope.items = [
            {
                'name': 'Item1',
                'price': 1200
            },
            {
                'name': 'Item2',
                'price': 1000
            },
            {
                'name': 'Item3',
                'price': 1600
            },
            {
                'name': 'Item4',
                'price': 2000
            },
            {
                'name': 'Item5',
                'price': 1800
            }
        ];
    }
]);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#last_element {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='SampleApp'>
  <div class='container' ng-controller='SampleCtrl'>
    <h4>「#last_element」だけ色を変える</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <div ng-attr-id="{{$last &amp;&amp; 'last_element'}}">名前: {{item.name}}, 値段: {{item.price}}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```